# Different sqlldr locations on load balanced nodes

Tags: linux, oracle

We have two nodes in a cluster in a load balancer running third party WebSphere application.

We have noticied that ./sqlldr location is different for both the nodes.
For one node , its:
`/usr/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client`

For another, , it is:
`/usr/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1`

I believe this is causing the problem in our WebSphere application whose configuration file has one path for setting ./sqlldr location.

Can you tell me how to best resolve this error without taking a big step such as reinstalling the product.

Would creating a symlink resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two choises:

1. Symlink (as you suggested) to make the paths identical. For example:

   ```
   $ ln -s /usr/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client /usr/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1
   ```
2. Create a conditional alias into the account's profile (assuming that the profiles must be identical). Into .bash_profile or other profile file that is read before accessing sqlldr:

   ```
   if [ `hostname` = "server_a" ]; then
       alias sqlldr='/usr/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client/bin/sqlldr'
   else
       alias sqlldr='/usr/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/sqlldr'
   fi
   ```

Both should work and I would first try the symlink option, since it may be considered simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that. Do you think that arguments of ls are reversed ?

Comment: `ln`'s arguments are in order `ln -s <source> <destination>`.

Comment: Ok, got it. It depends which path you are treating as the original/correct path.